# How are plant meristems free from viral infection?

Tags: botany, plant-physiology

My textbook mentions an application of tissue culture; A meristem extract from an infected plant (both apical and axillary work) can be used to grow a virus-free plant *in vitro*. But what makes these meristematic cells special so they don't get infected?

Edit:I read an article on a protein called WUSCHEL that inhibits the prodction of viral proteins (by halting protein production altogether). So is this protein the main reason?

Comment: Welcome to the Biology Stack Exchange. Please take the [tour] and visit the [help] for more information on this site and how it works. Please also note the [homework](https://biology.stackexchange.com/help/homework) requirement - so tell us what you know about this topic - hint: there are lots of answers easily accessible by searching.